# How do I load data to azure blob or Adls from Google search console?

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-data-factory, google-search-console

Requirements - How to load data from Google search console to Azure blob or ADLS

I don't see a direct connector from Azure DataFactory to Google search console. But there is a connector available for Google Big query.

1. Is there any direct way to fetch data from search console?
2. Is there a way to fetch data from Google search console using Apache Spark?

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this with AD and a POST request to Azure storage.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Use the APIs Google search console API to get the data needed https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/ Then use Azure API to POST the data.